# How to read from file, which name is "-"

Tags: file

how to read content of a file which name is "-" (dash, not stdin)?

Answer (score 7):

From any programming language, just open the file. A single dash is certainly no special file name and can be opened like any other one.

From a shell, you can use `./-`:

```
$ some_command --out foo --in ./-
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a utility that represents STDIN/STDOUT with `-`, try using `./-` or `-- -`.

Answer (score 1):

cat <- will work under *nix.

Answer (score 0):

No differently that from any other file.